# Python Syntax Error for no reason?

Tags: python

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "pymon.py", line 18
sql += "'" + str(gpu['GPU Clock'] + "', "
  ^
```

If it helps, this is (part of) the code:

```
def parsedata(data, ngpu):

for gpu in data:

    sql = "UPDATE pythondb SET (minerid, temp, load, hashrate, accepted, rejected, coreclock, memclock, power, hwerror) VALUES "
    sql += "("
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['Temperature']) + "', "
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['GPU Activity']) + "', "
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['MHS av'] * 1000) + "', "
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['Accepted']) + "', "
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['Rejected'] + "', "
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['GPU Clock'] + "', "
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['Memory Clock'] + "', "
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['GPU Voltage'] + "', "
    sql += "'" + str(gpu['Device Hardware']) + "'"
    sql += ") WHERE id='%d'", ngpu
    sql += ";"

return sqlstatement
```

I bet it's something very stupid, but i just cant find what it is.

Comment: *cough* parameterized statements? *cough*

Comment: I hope you have rock-solid verification of the contents of `gpu` before executing this code. It's a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations) attack waiting to happen.

Comment: LOL @ "for no reason"

Comment: FYI, you'll get better (and more positive) responses on S.O. if you can state your question more clearly and explain what you've already tried. Also, I have no idea what tools you're using, but consider finding a Python IDE (I use [Pyscripter](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/)) that will highlight syntax errors for you. It will let you get the value of `sqlstatement` while debugging - pasting the resulting string into a SQL editor would immediately highlight any SQL syntax errors as well.

Comment: I will take this into account. I've never asked a question on here so i was not confident of what to include. Also, it seems to me that Pyscripter is not avaliable on Linux, which is my OS. I've configured Eclipse for use with python though, which allows for some debugging!

Comment: I asked this question months ago and now feel extremely embarassed by it. God how could I ever have been this stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
sql += "'" + str(gpu['Memory Clock'] + "', "
#           ----^      but not here ^
```

The closing parenthesis for the `str()` function is missing from multiple lines.

You really should not use string interpolation to build a SQL query; you would use SQL *parameters* instead. How this works depends on your database adapter.

In `sqite3`, for example, you'd use `?` as a placeholder; MySQLdb uses `%s` instead. A sqlite example would be:

```
sql = """\
    UPDATE pythondb SET (
        minerid, temp, load, hashrate, accepted, rejected,
        coreclock, memclock, power, hwerror)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    WHERE id=?"
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (
    gpu['Temperature'], gpu['GPU Activity'], gpu['MHS av'] * 1000,
    gpu['Accepted'], gpu['Rejected'], gpu['GPU Clock'], gpu['Memory Clock'],
    gpu['GPU Voltage'], gpu['Device Hardware'])
)
```

Even if you could not use SQL parameters, you really should learn about [Python String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax); you could then have:

```
sql = """\
    UPDATE pythondb SET (
        minerid, temp, load, hashrate, accepted, rejected,
        coreclock, memclock, power, hwerror)
    VALUES (
        '{0[Temperature]}', '{0[GPU Activity]}',
        '{1}', '{0[Accepted]}', '{0[Rejected]}', '{0[GPU Clock]}',
        '{0[Memory Clock]}', '{0[GPU Voltage]}', '{0[Device Hardware]}')
   WHERE id='{2}';
""".format(gpu, gpu['MHS av'] * 1000, ngpu)
```

except that it's still a massively bad idea to interpolate SQL values into a SQL statement like that.

Comment: and there are other lines with missing paranthesises

Comment: @RickyA: the bigger problem is the approach.

Comment: you don't have to convince me. This is one of the most awful string builds I have seen :( But just for the sake of "hey I updated line 10 and it still fails" I mentioned it.

Comment: why is the bloody "@martijn-pieters" not working?

Comment: @RickyA: because I am the author of this post; I always get pinged. As a result, you don't have to use my name, and there is no auto-completion available.

Comment: Ah. well they could inject it anyhow. Wouldn't hurt visability...

Comment: Thank you very much guys, i'm a beginning programmer and i understand my approach is very bad. Everything is working now. Once again, thank you very much and excuse my noobness.